# Send Errors in PHP via E-Mail

Tags: php, email

I just discovered that PHP offers a function set_error_handler and was wondering if I could use this to have errors sent to me by mail rather displaying them on-page.

But would there be any point to using set_error_handler? Since E_ERROR won't be caught by that.

Or is there perhaps even a library that already does what I'm trying to do here?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure about email, but you could definitely check your error logs from time to time. if errors occur, they show up in the same folder as the file that the error occured on.

Comment: So what happens if the same error occurs 1,000 times in an hour? Do you really want 1,000 emails in your inbox?

Comment: checking error logs in a shared hosting environment is not always possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-email-error-logs-to-yourself-with-php/ this will help you.